# How to make the embedded system configurable without update the whole firmware

Tags: embedded, firmware

I'm totally a newbie in embedded software. Currently, I'm working on a project that implements an image processing pipeline on an ARM Cortex-M4 based MCU(board model: STM32F446RE).

I would like to be able to configure the parameters of the pipeline on the fly without actually update the entire firmware since we're using LoRa which has low bandwidth.

I have googled for several hours and could not find any valid solution. So could you please point me in a direction? Thank you very much.

BTW, I don't know if this is relevant, but I'm using FreeRTOS kernel with CMSIS RTOS API v2.

Comment: Can't you just send parameters using a serial connection or any other communication protocol? Then you just have to read and interpret the incoming data.

Comment: The question is too broad - there is no "one" applicable technique.  It depends entirely on the resources available to your application.  It is a design question, not a coding issue. In general, you accept configuration commands / data by whatever means, you store the configuration is whatever non-volatile storage available to your system, and you write the code to behave according to the configuration rather then hard-coding the behaviour/parameters.

Comment: The STM32F446RE has 4Kb backup SRAM - that is SRAM that is supplied through teh Vbatt power domain.  So if your board has a back-up battery supply or other secure power, you can use that for non-volatile storage.  But as you can see is actually several questions, how to receive the config data, how to store the data and how to load the data to determine the behaviour.  It also raises questions - just knowing the chip is insufficient; your board may have an EEPROM, or SD card for example.  It is a low-level embedded system, not Linus - there are few standard solutions; you have to _write code_.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking this question, I would hope that either:

1. The board is still under design or
2. You have a board that was designed by someone who has thought about these issues.

If #2, speak to whoever designed the board, and find out what resources were put in, to handle these issues.

If #1, presumably you have input into the design.

Necessary resources:

1. Non-volatile storage: flash, eeprom, etc.
2. One or more ways to write parameters to that non-volatile storage

Desirable resource:  communication line for input/output while running (serial is often used).

Once you have these resources, you do the following:

1. Design the variables, data structures, etc. to hold the parameters
2. Design your non-volatile storage, taking into account:

   a.  The features/limitations of your media (for example, flash memory generally requires an erase before writing. Erase takes time and must be done by sector, not individual bytes.

   b.  Verification: your program should have a way to verify that the non-volatile storage has valid values, not garbage, not all 0xFFs, and either fail or use defaults or some such, if it is not valid

Then you can write a program using this.

You need to consider how you will write the values to the non-volatile memory

- during development
- in production

They are not likely to be the same.

During development, you want to be able to easily change values.  You may have a way to burn your flash chip via a JTAG.  You may have a communications port which either runs some kind of simple CLI, accepts commands via some protocol, asks questions and reads the answers via a terminal emulator, etc.  The program can then write the values to the non-volatile memory.

In production, you will likely want to burn the 'correct' values once, when setting up the system, without too much operator involvement.

This is just a starting guideline...as mentioned in the comments, your question is very general.